# BigDecimal doesn't calculate divide

Tags: java

I divided 124/13. but the app forced close.
this is my code:

```
Float x =Float.valueOf(a.getText().toString());
Float y =Float.valueOf(b.getText().toString());
BigDecimal xx= new BigDecimal (x);
BigDecimal yy= new BigDecimal (y);
BigDecimal rx= xx.divide(yy);
res.setText("=" + rx);
```

Comment: On what line(s) is/are the error(s) happening?

Comment: There isn't error.the app forced close and ... . but in 120/10 it answers correctly

Comment: Next time, if you really cannot debug the error from within Android, please first verify if your code block (if it requires no Android framework) is even running in normal Java.

Comment: I tried but the app forced close again.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Logcat output?

Comment: The only difference I can think about is that `124/13` will give a long (infinite) result. Maybe your label cannot handle the size of the resulting String?

Comment: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: We need a bit more than that. Post the full stack trace

Comment: I wouldn't use `Float` the least accurate floating point with `BigDecimal`. I would use `double` or even better use only double or BigDecimal.  There is no need to use both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have encountered:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; 
    no exact representable decimal result.
```

Consider this example, which will yeld this exact exception:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(1);
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(3);
BigDecimal result = x.divide(y);
```

That's because there's no exact representation of `0.3333(3)`. 
What you need to do is to specify rounding and precision:

```
BigDecimal result = x.divide(y, 10 /*scale*/, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(result); //will print "0.3333333333"
```

---

Also note that you should create the `BigDecimal` directly from `String`, as `float` is not a precise representation. Consider this:

```
String s = "0.123456789";
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat(s)); //prints 0.12345679
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(s));   //prints 0.123456789
```

---

It may be the case that you want an approximate result. Then just go with `float` or `double` only:

```
dobule x = Double.parseDouble(a.getText());
dobule y = Double.parseDouble(b.getText());
res.setText("=" + (x/y));
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the app is crashing, because `BigDecimal.toString()` does something unexpected. Also `a`, or `b` or `rx` may be `null`.

In any way, I would consider using `BigDecimal` with the `String` constructor, such that no rounding errors occur:

```
String x = a.getText().toString();
String y = b.getText().toString();
BigDecimal xx = new BigDecimal(x);
BigDecimal yy = new BigDecimal(y);
BigDecimal rx = xx.divide(yy);
res.setText("=" + rx.toPlainString());
```

Also write `new BigDecimal(x)` instead of `new BigDecimal (x)`. Note the omitted space, that may be the very reason why your app crashes, it is not allowed in Java.

Comment: `new BigDecimal (x)` is perfectly legal Java syntax (though not recomended by [Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141388.html#682))